# Печатается из файла только последний элемент односвязного списка

Tags: c, односвязный-список, файловый-ввод-вывод

такая проблема что при чтение из файла и запись в односвязный список выводится в консоли только последний элемент который находился в списке

Т.е. вот мой файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что выводится в консоли :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще почему-то не выводятся цифры после запятой вместо них там всегда нули

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct prog
{
    char name[80];
    unsigned int kol;
    double time1;
    double time2;

    struct prog* next;
};

typedef struct prog* pcust;
pcust gol = NULL;

void list(prog* head);
struct prog* zad8(void);
pcust zad81(char* newname, int newkol, int newtime1, int newtime2);
void addlast(pcust* gol, pcust newprog);
void addfirst(pcust* gol, pcust newprog);
void addafter(pcust p, pcust newprog);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int b;

    struct prog* head = NULL;

    cout << "Введите 8 если записать список из файла >";
    cin >> b;
    if (b == 8)
    {
        head = zad8();
    }

    cout << "Введите 2 если хотите напечатать список >";
    cin >> b;
    if (b == 2)
    {
        list(head);
    }

    free(head);
}

void list(prog* head)
{
    prog* p;
    p = head;
    printf("\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|Время выполнения некоторых программ, которые применяют параллельные алгоритмы                          |\n");
    printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|Название программы|Количество строк ввода|Время исп. на SGI Callenge (cек)|Время исп. на SGI Indy (cек)|\n");
    printf("|------------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|----------------------------|\n");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("|%-18s|%-22u|%-32.2lf|%-28.2lf|\n", p->name, p->kol, p->time1, p->time2);
        printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        p = p->next;
    }
    _getch();
}



struct prog* zad8(void)
{
    FILE* g;
    fopen_s(&g, "fileG.txt", "r");
    struct prog newprog;
    struct prog* head = NULL;
    /*pcust my;*/
    while (fscanf(g, "%s\n%u\n%lf\n%lf\n", newprog.name, &newprog.kol, &newprog.time1, &newprog.time2) != EOF)
    {
        head = zad81(newprog.name, newprog.kol, newprog.time1, newprog.time2);
        addlast(&gol, head);
    }
    fclose(g);

    return head;
}

pcust zad81(char* newname, int newkol, int newtime1, int newtime2)
{
    pcust my;
    prog* newprog;
    my = newprog = (prog*)malloc(sizeof(prog));
    strcpy(newprog->name, newname);
    newprog->kol = newkol;
    newprog->time1 = newtime1;
    newprog->time2 = newtime2;
    newprog->next = NULL;
    return newprog;
}

void addlast(pcust* gol, pcust newprog)
{
    pcust q = *gol;
    if (*gol == NULL)
    {
        addfirst(gol, newprog);
        return;
    }
    while (q->next)
    {
        q = q->next;
    }
    addafter(q, newprog);
}

void addfirst(pcust* gol, pcust newprog)
{
    newprog->next = *gol;
    *gol = newprog;
}

void addafter(pcust p, pcust newprog)
{
    newprog->next = p->next;
    p->next = newprog;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему

Comment: По умолчанию (без указания локали) используется не десятичная запятая, а десятичная точка.

Comment: Harry, поотключал все локали, setconcole и в блокноте поставил везде точки место запятых а все равно не отображается при-чем в откладчике видно что в программу попадают десятичные числа это видимо из-за неправильности моей программы в функции zad8 в цикле while записываем в head результат именно там теряются цифры после знака

Comment: Понимаете, скажу откровенно - одно дело, когда есть минимальный пример с проблемой. И совсем другое - ковыряться со 135 строками чужого кода, де еще руками набирать код в файл с данными... Ну вот жаль времени, простите. Даешь совет на поверхности, а дальше - надо ковыряться и локализовать неприятности. А потом выяснится, что где-то какая-то буква пропущена - вот так оно обычно бывает... У вас же даже код нельзя просто взять и запихать компилятору - надо сидеть и руками порванные строки править!

Comment: Выводится только последний элемент списка, т.к. вы из `zad8()` вместо `go1` (кстати, не объявлена, а по смыслу указатель на весь список) возвращаете `head` (указатель на очередной прочитанный из файла элемент)

Comment: @avp, группа студентов пришла осваивать односвязные списки в различных комбинациях — они из одного ВУЗа? :)

Comment: @0andriy, может и так, но скорее всего один "шифруется"

Comment: @avp, не понимаю смысла. От преподавателя, который тоже здесь шарится (по их / его мнению)?

Comment: @0andriy, не знаю, можно у самого спросить (собственно, этот комментарий он получит и может быть удовлетворит наше любопытство)